# php request returns error 500 after creating subdomain

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

Hi everyone I've created a subdomain to my company website but I can not manage to execute php file from within the subdomain...
when I execute a php file it returns:
500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've added an empty .htaccess file in the subdomain folder but only html files work so far...

I don't really know where the problem is to be honest!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you take a look into error logs?

Comment: Check server error logs to see what's happening in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible reasons:

1)Error with an .htaccess file

If you are using a .htaccess on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the .htaccess configuration. Any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed instead of your website.

**To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and then try to reload the page.**

2) If your PHP script makes external network connections, the connections may time out. If too many connections are attempted and time out, this will cause a "500 Internal Server Error." To prevent these time outs and errors, you'll want to make sure that PHP scripts be coded with some timeout rules. Typically, however, catching a timeout error when connecting to a database or externally to remote resources (example: RSS feeds) are difficult. They, in effect, freeze the script from continuing to run.

**Removing any external connections can increase both the performance of your website and decrease the chances of you receiving a "500 Internal Server Error."**